# Making predictions from Keras Models

Tags: python, keras

I have a trained h5 model, the training data for that model required pre-processing to remove unwanted columns/features.
I want to run live inference on that model now, the live data however has lots of columns - how do I extract the exact features from the live data that were used to train the model..?
Do I have to do this or will the keras model see that I have the various columns in my new data and automatically make the right selection and ignore the other columns..?

Comment: No, you need to pre-process any new data in the same way you pre-processed the training set. Keras will not do it for you.

Comment: So how do I extract the predictor vars from my saved model..?